# Checking multiples of a number using a switch statement

Tags: java

For a Java programming assignment, I am required to use both `if`/`else` and `switch` statements to display if a number `n` is a multiple of `2`, `3`, `7` or `9`. Using an `if`/`else` is easy (e.g. `n % 7 == 0`), but I cannot seem to figure out how to implement this with a `switch` statement.

Comment: `switch (n%7){ case 0: ....  }`?

Comment: `I am working with Java by the way!!` is pretty unnecessary, considering you tagged it with the [tag:java] tag.

Comment: assignment seems pretty ridiculous, no matter how hard I think, a switch case doesn't seem very suited for this at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mildly ridiculous solution using the new Java 14 pattern matching syntax.

```
    boolean isMultiple = switch (n % 2) {
        case 0 -> true;
        default -> switch (n % 3) {
            case 0 -> true;
            default -> switch (n % 7) {
                case 0 -> true;
                default -> false;
            };
        };
    };
```

Comment: This is clever.  I like it.  You missed `9` though ;).- You don't need breaks with this new type of `case`, eh?

Comment: That is switch expression,  not switch statement.

Comment: @Steve any multiple of 9 is a multiple of 3.

Comment: Ah!  You got me there! - Just not thinking, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I can

```
 int arr[] = {2, 3, 7, 9};

        for (int number:arr) {

            int input = 9;
            int result = input % number;

            switch (result) {
                case 0:
                    System.out.println(input+" is multiple  of " + number);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println(input+" is not multiple of " + number);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  It simply iterates over nested switch blocks printing the appropriate results.

```
int[] candidates = { 10, 15, 19, 21, 6, 9 };
for (int candidate : candidates) {
    System.out.printf("%d is divisible by ", candidate);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    switch (candidate % 2) {
        case 0:
            sb.append(2).append(" ");
        default:
            switch (candidate % 3) {
                case 0:
                    sb.append(3).append(" ");
                default:
                    switch (candidate % 7) {
                        case 0:
                            sb.append(7).append(" ");
                        default:
                            switch (candidate % 9) {
                                case 0:
                                    sb.append(9).append(" ");
                                default:
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.length() > 0 ? sb.toString() :
            "none of the divisors.");
    
}
```

Prints

```
10 is divisible by 2 
15 is divisible by 3 
19 is divisible by none of the divisors.
21 is divisible by 3 7 
6 is divisible by 2 3 
9 is divisible by 3 9
```